# How do I fetch chainlink weather data from solana program (rust)?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, chainlink

I am using anchor framework/rust and would like an example that guides me on how to fetch chainlink weather data on Solana program. I am currently on solana devnet. I did not manage to get concrete example from chainlink website on how to get weather data from solana program.